# Atributos JSON de instancia TypeScript-Sequelize

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js, sequelize

EL TypeScript creé mi modelo con su respectiva instancia para Sequelize. El problema es que al consumir el modelo requiero acceder al un atributo **"name_injured"** de  **"resultSurvey"** que es un JSON pero me marca que no he declarado el atributo el la instancia.

Error :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
import { DataTypes, Model } from "sequelize";
import DbCVRConnection from "../db/connection";

interface CvrInstance extends Model {
    id: number;
    code: string;
    resultSurvey: JSON;
}

const CvrModel = DbCVRConnection.define<CvrInstance>('cvr', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    code: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    resultSurvey: {
        type: DataTypes.JSON
    }
});

export default CvrModel;
```

Comment: TS no encuentra esa propiedad en la interface `CvrInstance->resultSurvey`. Me parece que se debería tener mapeada la forma del JSON, es decir sus propiedades como `name_injured ` en una `interface` y luego en la interface `CvrInstance` asignas esta interface a `resultSurvey`